# Get list of elements using data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I must have a list of label elements with data-id attrib where I use labels values to set img on the main container.

Function changeimage was return nodelist with null elements but I don't have any idea why

Any solutions ?

```
function getState() {
         try {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "Default.aspx/jsrequest",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (data) {
                        $("#ajax").empty();
                         $.each(data, function () {
                           $("#ajax").append('<div id="ajaxcontent"> 
 </div>');
                              $("#ajaxcontent").addClass("ajaxcontent");
                              $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                               $("#ajaxcontent").append('<div class="view">' 
   + ' <label id="IdOfMachine">' 
    + v.MachineId 
   + '</label>'                                    
   + '<label class="MachineState" data-id= "' 
 + v.MachineId + ' " > '
+ v.CurrentStatus 
  + '</label > '
  + '<img id="ChangeImg" src="">' 
  + '</img>'
  + '<label id="MachineName">' 
  + v.MachineName 
  + '</label>'
  + '</div>');
                         });
                     });
                 },
                 error: function (response) {
                     alert("something wrong")
                 }
             });
         } catch (err) { }
     }



     window.onload = function () {
         getState();
         setInterval(function () {
            getState();
         }, 20000);
     }

     function ChangeImage() {
         let labels = document.querySelectorAll(["data-id"]);
         //here i need to loop over element list and then get lables values to set img which show current state of label 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change it to something like this:

```
function ChangeImage() {
  let labels = $('label[data-id]');
  $.each(labels, function(i, x) {
    var text = $(x).text();
  });
}
```

This should provide you with the text from the `label` equal to `v.CurrentStatus`

**demo**

```js
function ChangeImage() {
  let labels = $('label[data-id]');
  $.each(labels, function(i, x) {
    var text = $(x).text();
    console.log(text);
  });
}

ChangeImage()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label data-id="1">test1</label>
<label data-id="2">test2</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer I will test it tommorw in office, but in loop I need to set img src which is dependent of label state (active,error or other state of machine)  and everything do in this one loop yea ?

Comment: @Przeklin You haven't show how you want the img src to look like

Comment: for example If label value was "active" in img src  set path to the green circle when label was change to "ERROR" it's automaticly set path to the red circle.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using css selector

```
function ChangeImage() {
   let labels = $('.MachineState').map(() => {
      let item = {
          id:    $(this).data('id'),
          value: $(this).text()
      }

      let imgUrl = `${item.id}-${item.value}.jpg` // for example
      $(this).closest('img').attr('src', imgUrl)

      return item
   });

}
```

This will generate list of object like this 
[{id: 1, value: 'label1'}, {id: 2, value: 'label2'}, ...]